# Best wavelet for iris recognition

Tags: image-processing, wavelet-transform, iris-recognition

Does anybody know which kind of wavelet is better for feature extraction 
in Iris Recognition?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had checked many of them but i prefer 2D Gabor wavelets (Daugman 1994).